# Sorting a list of HtmlElements by Text

Tags: dart

i am trying to sort `List<HtmlElement>` by `Text`, Text is parsed as num

```dart
 this.onClick.listen((e){
     this.parent.nextElementSibling.children.sort((Row a,Row b)=>
         num.parse(a.children[this.visibleIndex].text).
         compareTo(num.parse(b.children[this.visibleIndex].text)));
    });
```

`Row` is a class that extends `HtmlElement`

and i get the exception

```dart
Unsupported operation: Cannot sort element lists
```

is there a work around or do i have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it but I think it should work when you add `.toList()`. I think this should copy it to a standard list which is sortable.

```dart
 this.onClick.listen((e){
     this.parent.nextElementSibling.children.toList().sort((Row a,Row b)=>
         num.parse(a.children[this.visibleIndex].text).
         compareTo(num.parse(b.children[this.visibleIndex].text)));
    });
```

Comment: but this won't modify the list of children if its already rendered and it means i need to reassign it, right?

Comment: You are right. But there is no way around when it doesn't allow sorting, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:html';

UListElement list;
ButtonInputElement boton;
main() {
  list = querySelector('#list'); 
  boton.onClick.listen( (e) => sort() );
}

void sort(){
  list.children = list.children.toList()
                  ..sort((LIElement x, LIElement y)=> y.text.length.compareTo(x.text.length) );  
}
```